# Android Studio 2.1.1 emulator crashing on Mac

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, android-studio-2.0

I am using **Android Studio version 2.1.1. on Mac (running OS X 10.11.6)**. Recently, I found that the emulators are **crashing** on launch. Earlier the same emulators were working properly.

Here is the **exception report** I get when I launch emulator:

```
    Process:               emulator64-arm [613]
    Path:                  /Users/USER/Library/Android/*/emulator64-arm
    Identifier:            emulator64-arm
    Version:               0
    Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
    Parent Process:        studio [560]
    Responsible:           emulator64-arm [613]
    User ID:               501

    Date/Time:             2016-10-24 11:59:53.840 +0530
    OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.6 (15G1004)
    Report Version:        11
    Anonymous UUID:        6844F1F8-F647-09F6-8FB0-A7B9C14F843B


    Time Awake Since Boot: 2000 seconds

    System Integrity Protection: enabled

    Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

    Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
    Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xfffffffffffffff0
    Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

    VM Regions Near 0xfffffffffffffff0:
    --> shared memory          00007ffffffb3000-00007ffffffb4000 [    4K] r-x/r-x SM=SHM  

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=241.0M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=241.0M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=105.4M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=105.4M(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Accelerate.framework               256K        3 
Activity Tracing                  2048K        2 
CG backing stores                  336K        3 
CG image                             8K        3 
CG shared images                   208K        6 
CoreUI image data                   80K        2 
CoreUI image file                  192K        6 
Dispatch continuations            8192K        2 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        3 
MALLOC                            63.9M       19 
MALLOC guard page                   32K        7 
MALLOC_LARGE (reserved)            752K        2         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
OpenCL                               8K        2 
Process Corpse Info               2048K        2 
STACK GUARD                       56.0M        8 
Stack                             10.6M        8 
VM_ALLOCATE                         52K        7 
__DATA                            20.4M      223 
__IMAGE                            528K        2 
__LINKEDIT                        93.0M        5 
__TEXT                           147.9M      231 
__UNICODE                          552K        2 
mapped file                       43.8M        9 
shared memory                     16.3M        7 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                            466.9M      540 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space   466.1M      540 

Model: Macmini7,1, BootROM MM71.0220.B07, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.6 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.24f32
Graphics: Intel Iris, Intel Iris, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B3445364533303445452D45474345000000
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B3445364533303445452D45474345000000
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x13B), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.95.175.1a6)
Bluetooth: Version 4.4.6f1 17910, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD HTS541010A9E662, 1 TB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Dell USB Keyboard
USB Device: USB Optical Mouse
Thunderbolt Bus: Mac mini, Apple Inc., 26.1
```

**I have tried following approaches:**

1. Clearing app caches and restarting Mac
2. Restarting Android Studio
3. Updating HAXM and other SDK tools

**Question:**

What could be the possible issue for this crash and how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: A few days ago 2.2.2 was released. Try that and see if you still get errors and report back -- http://tools.android.com/download/studio/stable

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I don't want to upgrade Android Studio to version 2.2.2. Are there any other approaches I can try?

Comment: You can try and add more memory to the VM

Comment: I think it can't be issue related to memory because until yesterday all the emulators were working properly and I haven't installed new software on my Mac which can consume RAM.